Internal Compiler Error: Segmentation Fault
I am getting the following error every time I try to build or make a package:
In file included from /usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/AxisAlignedBox.hh:25,
                 from /home/jjayalekshmi/gz-rendering-cpy/include/gz/rendering/Visual.hh:21,
                 from /home/jjayalekshmi/gz-rendering-cpy/src/Visual.cc:18:
/usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/MassMatrix3.hh: In member function ‘gz::math::v7::Vector3<T> gz::math::v7::MassMatrix3<T>::PrincipalMoments(T) const’:
/usr/include/gz/math7/gz/math/MassMatrix3.hh:498:20: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
  498 |         T p = std::pow(b, 2) - 3*c;
      |                    ^~~
0x78952a04251f ???
    ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
0x78952a029d8f __libc_start_call_main
    ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
0x78952a029e3f __libc_start_main_impl
    ../csu/libc-start.c:392
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/build.make:930: src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/Visual.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1626: src/CMakeFiles/gz-rendering8.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2

The error does not always occur on the same line.
I ran MemTest for 17 hours and it ran without errors. I have also under-clocked the CPU to ensure the system is not overheating.
I have downgraded to gcc version 11.4.0
PC build details:
I am using the MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk motherboard, TeamGroup T-Force Vulcan 32GB (2x16GB) RAM, Intel Core i9-14900K 24 cores 14th Gen CPU and a Tesla P100 GPU.
What can I do next to try and fix this issue?
P.S.: This is a new system and these programs were running without any issues at the time. I started facing these issues after not using the system for a week and the computer for left on during this period. The system was hanging when I came back. I have tried reinstalling the OS. I have also tried running it on a single RAM. And the system still hangs every now and then.

Did you “Submit a full bug report” as said in the error message?

Could it be a hardware fault that only showed up after burn-in? If you can substitute motherboard and/or GPU, then that issue could be eliminated. Hpever, obviously that would be a lot of work. sigh

Yes, I submitted a full bug report to the gcc bug tracker, but did not get any proper response yet.

And yes, prior to this the system has not been left running for long periods of time.

(Not a definitive answer, but answering anyway because I can't comment. )
I have a very similar setup (same mobo, same CPU). I have however not under-clocked the CPU.
I did run a 12-ish hour-long MemTest that did not reveal any memory issue.
I'm using GCC 13.3.1 and I get seemingly random internal compiler errors (segfaults, stack smashing, illegal instructions, …) when compiling GCC or the Linux kernel.
These do not seem to happen for smaller compiles. I've reinstalled the OS (was previously using an earlier GCC version) and still see the same symptoms.
With the issue happening at seemingly random points in the build, with different but not all build targets (GCC/kernel but not smaller stuff), and at least 2 GCC versions, I'm rather inclined to think this is a hardware bug rather than a GCC one.
I suspect this is due to the recently revealed voltage issues on Intel 13th/14th gen CPUs: https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/1e9mf04/intel_core_13th14th_gen_desktop_processors/

Based on extensive analysis of Intel Core 13th/14th Gen desktop processors returned to us due to instability issues, we have determined that elevated operating voltage is causing instability issues in some 13th/14th Gen desktop processors. Our analysis of returned processors confirms that the elevated operating voltage is stemming from a microcode algorithm resulting in incorrect voltage requests to the processor.
Intel is delivering a microcode patch which addresses the root cause of exposure to elevated voltages. We are continuing validation to ensure that scenarios of instability reported to Intel regarding its Core 13th/14th Gen desktop processors are addressed. Intel is currently targeting mid-August for patch release to partners following full validation.

The new microcode has been released by Intel a couple of days ago: https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/Microcode-0x129-Update-for-Intel-Core-13th-and-14th-Gen-Desktop/m-p/1622129

Intel is currently distributing to its OEM/ODM partners a new microcode patch (0x129) for its Intel Core 13th/14th Gen desktop processors which will address incorrect voltage requests to the processor that are causing elevated operating voltage.
For all Intel Core 13th/14th Gen desktop processor users: This patch is being distributed via BIOS update and will not be available through operating system updates. Intel is working with its partners to ensure timely validation and rollout of the BIOS update for systems currently in service.

...

Intel has released three mitigations related to the instability issue – commonly experienced as consistent application crashes and repeated hangs – to help stabilize customer systems with Intel Core 13th and 14th gen desktop processors:

Intel default settings to avoid elevated power delivery impact to the processor (May 2024)
Microcode 0x125 to fix the eTVB issue in i9 processors (June 2024)
Microcode 0x129 to address elevated voltages (August 2024)


I'll update and report back once MSI provides a BIOS upgrade for it.
EDIT:

the MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk has the 0x129 ucode BIOS available: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-Z790-TOMAHAWK-WIFI/support
the MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk Max (which I have) doesn't have the 0x129 ucode BIOS available yet: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-Z790-TOMAHAWK-MAX-WIFI/support


Yes, I believe this was the issue, I had updated my bios to the latest version 7E25vA62(Beta version) a week back and haven’t faced any issues since.
